# Copy mysql database into sqlite database

Tags: mysql, xcode, sqlite

I have a mysql database which I use for my website. Is there any way how I can copy this database into my ios app where I am using sqlite to fetch data so that I dont need to create the database again.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Neha

Answer (score 0):

This converter might do the job: [MySQL to Sqlite converter](https://gist.github.com/esperlu/943776)